# Cannot made "delete" in popup richfaces panel

Tags: java, jboss, richfaces

I am working on simple application with richfaces 3.3.3, and I would like to "remove" an item from an extended table

here is my bean code

```
public void  remove(){
        System.out.println("suppression effectué" + this.selected);

    }
```

---

this is my panel code

```
<rich:modalPanel domElementAttachment="form" id="confirmation" autosized="true">
            Are you sure you want to delete the row?
            <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide(); return false;" />
            <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{backGesDS.remove}" />
            </h:form>
        </rich:modalPanel>
```

---

but unfortunately I've got this error

```
      javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.ELException: /gesDS.xhtml @53,172 onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.show();return false": Function 'rich:component' not found
```

could you please help me ???

Comment: Terrible english btw :P

Comment: thanks, any answer on this?

Comment: Nope sorry not my programming language :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer from what i understand from your question
change your onclick code in `cancel` button with this code

```
onclick="if (!ajaxRequestContainsErrors()) Richfaces.hideModalPanel('confirmation');"
```

here you get error for `cancel` button not for `delete` button.
and if possible change `h:commandButton` with `a4j:commandButton` to hide model panel with out page refresh